# Using ObjectQuery Include and using a nested where clause

Tags: entity-framework, nested

Using entity framework, I'm trying to get back a customer with order details but I want to filter out those Orders that are active.

Customer is our EntityObject which has a collection of Order EntityObjects.  CustomerDetails is our ObjectContext.

The code below will attach all orders but I want to filter and only attach those that are active.  (Order.active == true).  How can I do this?

I know Include builds up a nested query statement (I can observe by using .ToTraceString().)  I was hoping to attach a Where clause to this nested select statement or the Include.

```
            Customer cust;
        CustomerDetails custTable = new CustomerDetails();


        cust = custTable.Customer
            .Where("it.cust_id = " + id)
            .Include("Order")  // But we only want Order.active == true!!!
            .ToList().First();
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but might work?

```
var temp = custTable.Customer.Where("it.cust_id = " + id).Include("Order");
cust = (from t in temp 
        where t.Order.active == true 
        select t).ToList().First();
```